# Can rpart work with both numeric and categorical data?

Tags: r, decision-tree

I'm trying to train a model in R using both categorical and numeric data to predict whether a customer purchased something, and when I plot the tree to look at the splits it completely ignored gender.

As seen below, I encoded the gender variables to be just 1 and 2. 
There's roughly an even split between both males and females. 
I didn't scale any features.

```
head(df1)
  Gender Age EstimatedSalary Purchased
1      2  19              19         0
2      2  35              20         0
3      1  26              43         0
4      1  27              57         0
5      2  19              76         0
6      2  27              58         0
```

[I can provide this link showing the decision tree.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeRFf.png)

Is gender simply not significant for this prediction, or am I missing something else?

Comment: Yes, it does. You should set your categorical variables as factors using `?factor`

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Yeah I'd already done that

Comment: Without a reprex, it's hard to see that from what you've posted. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example . It's not enough to "encode" them, they have to be factors to. Please show us more. Maybe the results of `summary(rpart.model)` where `rpart.model` is the variable that holds your model after running `rpart()`